# Efficiency of the matrix multiplication of three matrices

Tags: matrices

I would appreciate if someone could help me with this problem. I have tried to find a general expression for the multiplication of three matrices but wasn't successful in my pursuit.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mRyM.png)

Comment: You're doing too much. Instead consider how you can reduce the size of the matrix at each step by placing the parenthesis. You should only be calculating on the size of the matrix without regard to the entries.